# Jest Mock function is called but jest toHaveBeenCalledTimes returns 0

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, mocking, react-testing-library

I am testing a function call.

Header.js

```
function Header({ userLogout, ...props }) {

const [openDialog, setOpenDialog] = React.useState(false);

 const handleOpenDialog = () => {
    setOpenDialog(true);
  };

const handleDialogClose = (event, shouldLogout) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (shouldLogout) {
      userLogout(true);
    }
    setOpenDialog(false);
  };

 return (
<>
  <div onClick={handleOpenDialog}>Logout</div>

 <Dialog
        open={openDialog}
        onClose={handleDialogClose}
        aria-labelledby="logout-dialog"
      >
                <DialogContent>
          <DialogContentText data-testid="message">
            You are about to be logged out.
            <br />
            Are you sure?
          </DialogContentText>
        </DialogContent>
        <DialogActions>
          <Button onClick={handleDialogClose} color="primary" name="cancel">
            Cancel
          </Button>
          <Button
            onClick={(e) => handleDialogClose(e, true)}
            color="primary"
            name="logout"
          >
            Log out
          </Button>
        </DialogActions>
      </Dialog>
</>
)
}
Header.propTypes = {
  userLogout: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  userLogout,
};

export default withRouter(connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Header));
```

Header.test.js

```
import React from "react";
import Header from "./Header";
import "./setupTests";
import * as utils from "./Utils/utils";
import { rtlRender } from "./setupTests";
import { screen, fireEvent, waitFor } from "@testing-library/react";
const user = {
  token: "test token",
  authExpireTime: date.setHours(date.getHours() + 1),
  name: "abc",
};

const initialState = {
  userLogout: jest.fn(),
  history: {},
  match: {},
};
function render() {
  return rtlRender(<Header />, {
    initialState: initialState,
  });
}

describe("test logout dialog", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.spyOn(utils, "getLocalStorage").mockReturnValue(user);
    render();

    const logoutBtn = screen.getByText("Logout");
    fireEvent.click(logoutBtn);
  });

test("should call userLogout function when user clicks on Logout", async () => {
    const logoutBtn = screen.getByRole("button", { name: /LOG OUT/i });
    fireEvent.click(logoutBtn, { shouldLogout: true });

    await waitFor(() => {
      expect(initialState.userLogout).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    });
  });
});
```

Error:

```
expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(expected)

    Expected number of calls: 1
    Received number of calls: 0
```

When I debug the unit test, it does goes to userLogout function, still the test is failing.

[image]

Comment: First of all are you getting the `logout` button instance ?

Comment: Yes, I am getting the logout button, the click event is fired. there is no error till that step. test fails on expect code only. When I debug the test, it does goes to userLogout function call.